# Using data from controller in view

Tags: zend-framework, parameters, controller, view

I have a question about using parameters from the controller in the view.
This is my situation:

In my Controller I have :

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $projectTitle = $project->getName();
}
```

Now In my view I want to show every title from a project in a table.
How can I do this the right way? I also want to create a link with in my view like this :

> "controller/action/projectid/1"

to edit the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have an array called `$titles` and do `an array_push` inside the for loop like this:

```
array_push($titles,$project->getName())
```

And send the $titles directly to the view?

Comment: And then loop through the array $titles in my view?

Comment: Yes..Exactly.
A better way is to make sure you send the $projects array into the view itself if your view can use getName on each $project object. You can also look for generating $projects as an array of arrays so that you can send it straight to the view